# Something wrong with API or in the Loop?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

So I have this function that fetches API response.

Here's what the API return response looks like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response type="1">
<ack>
    <ackstatus>OK</ackstatus>
    <ackreason></ackreason>
</ack>
<dataversion>1</dataversion>
<hitcount>13391</hitcount>
<shops>
    <spad>
                </spad>
    <basead>
        <shop>
            <id>KN0100060500216636</id>
            <priority>1</priority>
            <entryname>旭川職業能力開発促進センター</entryname>
            <telno>0166-48-2412</telno>
            <zipcode>079-8418</zipcode>
            <address>北海道旭川市永山８条２０丁目３−１</address>
            <latitude>157707796</latitude>
            <longitude>512803967</longitude>
            <imageurl></imageurl>
            <promoword></promoword>
            <coupon>0</coupon>
            <group>0</group>
            <searchnum>7214223</searchnum>
        </shop>
        <shop>
            <id>KN0100060500202256</id>
            <priority>1</priority>
            <entryname>旭川市立／嵐山小中学校</entryname>
            <telno>0166-61-1199</telno>
            <zipcode>070-8051</zipcode>
            <address>北海道旭川市江丹別町嵐山１４３</address>
            <latitude>157704475</latitude>
            <longitude>512195888</longitude>
            <imageurl></imageurl>
            <promoword></promoword>
            <coupon>0</coupon>
            <group>0</group>
            <searchnum>7214223</searchnum>
        </shop>
    </basead>
</shops>
</Response>
```

So in my function I have to fetch some details, example; id, entryname, so that I could use them as parameters to get a different API:

Here's the function;
(I put logs so if I run the script it shows what the results have got.)

```
public function getcompList($prefectureId,$industryId,$offset)
{
    $itpCompanies = $this->itpApi->getCompanies($prefectureId,$industryId,$offset);
    $hascompany = $this->itpApi->getReturnArray();

    log_message('debug','Company list fetched, returning...');

    return $hascompany;
}

public function getcompanyList($hascompany,$prefectureId,$offset,$industryId)
{
    foreach ( $hascompany['shops']['basead']['shop'] as $company ) {
        $companyId = $company['id'];
        $entryName = $company['entryname'];
        $priority = $company['priority'];
        $searchNum = $company['searchnum'];

        log_message('debug', 'Comp_List API: company_id = ' . print_r($companyId, true));
        log_message('debug', 'Comp_List API: company_name = ' . print_r($entryName, true));
        log_message('debug', 'Comp_List API: company_prio = ' . print_r($priority, true));
        log_message('debug', 'Comp_List API: company_searchno = ' . print_r($searchNum, true));

        log_message('debug', 'Company_List->Company_Detail:: Getting Company Detail...');
        $this->compModel->getDetail($prefectureId,$offset,$industryId,$companyId,$entryName,$priority,$searchNum);
    }

}
```

So for example in the above API response, the logs will show;

```
Company list fetched, returning...
Comp_List API: company_id = KN0100060500216636
Comp_List API: company_name = 旭川職業能力開発促進センター
Comp_List API: company_prio = 1
Comp_List API: company_searchno = 7214223
Company_List->Company_Detail:: Getting Company Detail...
Company Detail Inserted!
Comp_List API: company_id = KN0100060500202256
Comp_List API: company_name = 旭川市立／嵐山小中学校
Comp_List API: company_prio = 1
Comp_List API: company_searchno = 7214223
Company_List->Company_Detail:: Getting Company Detail...
Company Detail Inserted!
```

The problem is when API response returns only 1 `<shop>`. It gives me this;

```
Comp_List API: company_id = K
Comp_List API: company_name = K
Comp_List API: company_prio = K
Comp_List API: company_searchno = K
Company_List->Company_Detail:: Getting Company Detail...
```

and because this function is also inside a loop that checks and gets the API, The result would then give me error; a duplicate query, etc.

could it be a problem in the API? or the `foreach` loop in the `getcompanyList` function?

Comment: Is the XML structure different when there is only one result? Also, life is much easier with JSON (if you can choose your response type)

Comment: The XML structure is the same and the data being returned is in JSON. sorry I forgot to mention that I have a function that gets the API then parse it after.

Comment: So, if you can supply the JSON for both result types, I will copy and paste it into an example, and give you an answer. Add it to your question as `code`.

Comment: I reviewed my codes and tested it in local, and I think the problem is in the loop.

Comment: I provided an answer with a working loop. Maybe it will help you in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why you'd have a problem with a single result, but since you provided XML I used it and made 2 versions, one with the two results, and one that has a single result. I altered your loop, and was able to get the data regardless of which version of the XML I used. This is a full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php

function logCompanyData( $shops )
{
    foreach ( $shops as $company )
    {
        $companyId = $company->id;
        $entryName = $company->entryname;
        $priority  = $company->priority;
        $searchNum = $company->searchnum;

        echo 'debug: Comp_List API: company_id = ' . $companyId . '<br />';
        echo 'debug: Comp_List API: company_name = ' . $entryName . '<br />';
        echo 'debug: Comp_List API: company_prio = ' . $priority . '<br />';
        echo 'debug: Comp_List API: company_searchno = ' . $searchNum . '<br />';
        echo 'debug: Company_List->Company_Detail:: Getting Company Detail...' . '<br /><br />';
    }
}

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response type="1">
    <ack>
        <ackstatus>OK</ackstatus>
        <ackreason></ackreason>
    </ack>
    <dataversion>1</dataversion>
    <hitcount>13391</hitcount>
    <shops>
        <spad></spad>
        <basead>
            <shop>
                <id>KN0100060500216636</id>
                <priority>1</priority>
                <entryname>旭川職業能力開発促進センター</entryname>
                <telno>0166-48-2412</telno>
                <zipcode>079-8418</zipcode>
                <address>北海道旭川市永山８条２０丁目３−１</address>
                <latitude>157707796</latitude>
                <longitude>512803967</longitude>
                <imageurl></imageurl>
                <promoword></promoword>
                <coupon>0</coupon>
                <group>0</group>
                <searchnum>7214223</searchnum>
            </shop>
            <shop>
                <id>KN0100060500202256</id>
                <priority>1</priority>
                <entryname>旭川市立／嵐山小中学校</entryname>
                <telno>0166-61-1199</telno>
                <zipcode>070-8051</zipcode>
                <address>北海道旭川市江丹別町嵐山１４３</address>
                <latitude>157704475</latitude>
                <longitude>512195888</longitude>
                <imageurl></imageurl>
                <promoword></promoword>
                <coupon>0</coupon>
                <group>0</group>
                <searchnum>7214223</searchnum>
            </shop>
        </basead>
    </shops>
</Response>';

$xml2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response type="1">
    <ack>
        <ackstatus>OK</ackstatus>
        <ackreason></ackreason>
    </ack>
    <dataversion>1</dataversion>
    <hitcount>13391</hitcount>
    <shops>
        <spad></spad>
        <basead>
            <shop>
                <id>KN0100060777777777</id>
                <priority>7</priority>
                <entryname>旭川職業能力開発促進センター</entryname>
                <telno>0166-48-7777</telno>
                <zipcode>079-7777</zipcode>
                <address>北海道旭川市永山８条２０丁目３−１</address>
                <latitude>157707796</latitude>
                <longitude>512803967</longitude>
                <imageurl></imageurl>
                <promoword></promoword>
                <coupon>0</coupon>
                <group>0</group>
                <searchnum>7777777</searchnum>
            </shop>
        </basead>
    </shops>
</Response>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml );

logCompanyData( $xml->shops->basead->shop );

$xml2 = simplexml_load_string( $xml2 );

logCompanyData( $xml2->shops->basead->shop );

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much! Based in your code example, I changed my codes to;

$companyId = $company->id;
$entryName = $company->entryname;
$priority  = $company->priority;
$searchNum = $company->searchnum;

and also...

logCompanyData( $xml->shops->basead->shop );